# Remove biomentric data from smartcard

Tags: windows-7, biometrics

I am trying to remove the recorded fingerprint information from a smartcard using the Windows Biometric Framework.

I can delete the recorded fingerprints with the following steps:

opening a session

```
WinBioOpenSession
```

logging in using the fingerprint reader

```
WinBioLogonIdentifiedUser
```

read the availabe used fingerprints

```
WinBioEnumEnrollments
```

remove the fingerprint information

```
WinBioDeleteTemplate
```

But this only works when the user is avaliable!

**Is there a way to remove biometric information as card-administrator?**

Edit: I am using a Gemalto SmartCard.