# accessing a G0 5500 idprime .NET card to store fingerprint templates

Tags: .net, templates, smartcard, fingerprint, biometrics

I have the current problem: I need to store fingerprint templates using a precise biometric reader into a gemalto G0 55000 idprime bio .NET card.

gemalto does not provide any sort of documentation about how to do that ( or I did not find it so far ) and they just mention that the card is WBF - [Windows Biometric Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - compliant.

I did not found so far examples of code that show how to use WBF to store the templates into a smartcard. I am doing some tests with the WBF functions to see if the card is listed when I call the enumeration of the biometric devices from WBF or if I can see the card template database using a similar function. (WinBioAsyncEnumBiometricUnits,WinBioAsyncEnumDatabases)

I found that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447271/remove-biomentric-data-from-smartcard) which mention that the deletion of templates on a card can be done with WBF , but it does not explain how to open a session to the card.

How is it possible to store the captured fingerprint templates to the card using only WBF?

Comment: ok so far we located a storage plugin provided by precise biometrics in a dll, with functions :

WbioQueryEngineInterface
WbioQueryStorageInterface

these two functions are the implementation of a plugin for a storage interface as described [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401594(v=vs.85).aspx)there

Comment: That may be a bit too specific for the website; you may have the luck that somebody knows about this specific problem, but that kind of information normally prompts for research...